# Error in hiding/showing div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**The Story**

We have a parent (div). Parent can have n children. The number of children the parent can have is decided by a PHP variable `$bigF`.

So, if `$bigF` is 5, then parent has 5 children. If it's 10, then it's 10. But `$bigF` has no role in this context because once the page is loaded, parent will have n children. 
It's not dynamic, you know, that's what I was trying to say.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child1" class="click" style="display:block">
         Child1
         <div id="grandchild1A">
             grand child 1A
        </div>
         <div id="grandchild1B">
             grand child 1B
        </div>        
    </div>

     <div id="child2" class="click" style="display:none">
         Child2
         <div id="grandchild2A">
             grand child 2A
        </div>
        <div id="grandchild2B">
             grand child 2B
        </div>
    </div>

      <div id="child3" class="click" style="display:none">
         Child3
         <div id="grandchild3A">
             grand child 3A
        </div>
        <div id="grandchild3B">
             grand child 3B
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>

<br><br><br>
 Calling children down
 <br><br>
  <div class="callchild" data-count="child1"> Call Child 1</div>
  <div class="callchild" data-count="child2"> Call Child 2</div>
  <div class="callchild" data-count="child3"> Call Child 3</div>
```

In this example, parent has 3 children (div) and they are named child1,child2,child3. IDK who names a child child. That's bad parenting.
And the freaking thing about this family drama is every child has 2 children(div). And they have bizarre names like grandchild1A,grandchild1B, grandchild2A and so on....

Parent is kinda shy. She believes **only 1 child should be shown** to the outside world. **Rest of 'em are kept hidden**, may be in the basement or something.
But she has this one BIG rule written all over her face.
**If I CALL OUT A CHILD, THE CHILD AND THE GRANDCHILDREN SHOULD COME.**

And she has employed 3 guards- who makes her job easy. 
And they are Call Child 1,Call Child 2,Call Child 3.

And this is how they do their job.

```
<script>
    $(".callchild").on('click',function()
    {   
        //var calling = $('div:visible').last().attr('id');
        //alert(calling);        
        var calling = $(this).attr('data-count');
        $("#parent div:visible").hide();
        $('#'+calling).css("display","block");
    });
</script>
```

But every time they call a child, something bizarre happens. Sometimes child & the grandchildren come together. And some other time, the grand children went missing.

And they tried another way also, like:

```
var calling = $('div:visible').last().attr('id');
```

and returned with nothing.

Here's the proof. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamsajeev/v4u5zuhm/1/)

Can anyone help me investigate this story???
I offer Thanks in return. :)

Comment: No answer or suggestion, just saying its nicely written.

Comment: It is a riveting story. This is how movies for developers will be scripted. `<script type="text/movie"></script>`

Comment: Thanks for the entertaining question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The guards are hiding the grandchildren with this line:

```
$("#parent div:visible").hide();
```

because the grandchildren are divs within the parent.  You need to apply that operation to just the immediate children of the parent, using `>`:

```
$("#parent > div:visible").hide();
```

Comment: The missing children found. Are you Mr. Sherlock Holmes? @RichieHindle

Comment: My true identity shall remain a mystery.

Answer (score 2):

It's a nice story, but a little confusing :)
If your goal is to toggle the children and grandchildren using the data-count attribute, try this:

```
$(".callchild").on('click',function(){         
    var calling = $(this).attr('data-count');
    $("#parent > div").hide();
    $('#'+calling).css("display","block");
});
```

Find an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v4u5zuhm/3/) here.

Answer (score 2):

Great narration,Hatsoff.

I have modified the code little bit.
Please have a look at it.

```js
 $(".callchild").click(function()
    {   
       
        var calling = $(this).attr('data-count');
       $('.click').hide();
        $('#'+calling).show();
    });
```

```css
.callchild{
  background:aqua;
  width:100px;
  height:15px;
  border-radius:15px;
  padding:15px;
  margin:15px;
  cursor:pointer;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child1" class="click" style="display:block">
         Child1
         <div id="grandchild1A">
             grand child 1A
        </div>
         <div id="grandchild1B">
             grand child 1B
        </div>        
    </div>

     <div id="child2" class="click" style="display:none">
         Child2
         <div id="grandchild2A">
             grand child 2A
        </div>
        <div id="grandchild2B">
             grand child 2B
        </div>
    </div>

      <div id="child3" class="click" style="display:none">
         Child3
         <div id="grandchild3A">
             grand child 3A
        </div>
        <div id="grandchild3B">
             grand child 3B
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>

<br><br><br>
 Calling children down
 <br><br>
  <div class="callchild" data-count="child1"> Call Child 1</div>
  <div class="callchild" data-count="child2"> Call Child 2</div>
  <div class="callchild" data-count="child3"> Call Child 3</div>
```

Comment: You made things colorful.  Upvote and thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another working solution:

```
$(".callchild").on('click',function()
{         
    var calling = $(this).attr('data-count');
    $("#parent div:visible").hide();
    $('#'+calling).css("display","block");
    $('#'+calling+"  div").css("display","block");
});
```

I came to this solution because `$("#parent div:visible").hide();` also hiding children elements, so i have added `$('#'+calling+"  div").css("display","block");` to show respective children also.

[**--Working DEMO--**](http://jsfiddle.net/e4fmsgya/)

Answer (score 0):

In you fiddle just updat $("#parent div:visible").hide(); to $("#parent > div:visible").hide();

```
$(".callchild").on('click',function()
{   
    //var calling = $('div:visible').last().attr('id');
    //alert(calling);        
    var calling = $(this).attr('data-count');
    $("#parent > div:visible").hide();
    $('#'+calling).css("display","block");
});
```